# in my code textview not show bold what will i do?

Tags: android

in my fourthscree class selected text will not show bold only Breakfast wil show bold  Lunch and supper not shoe bold when i press img2 or img3 tell me what will i do??          all values show on Toast but not maketext bold only when pres img  is make Breakfast will be bold lunch and supper not show bold

```
  img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(thirdstep.this,
                    fourthscreen.class);

            iMenuList.putExtra("Menuitem", txt1.getText().toString());

            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });

    img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(thirdstep.this,
                    fourthscreen.class);

            iMenuList.putExtra("Menuitem", txt2.getText().toString());

            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });

    img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(thirdstep.this,
                    fourthscreen.class);

            iMenuList.putExtra("Menuitem", txt3.getText().toString());

            startActivity(iMenuList);

        }
    });

}

  }


       public class fourthscreen extends Activity

            Breakfast = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtfourth1);
    Lunch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtfourth2);
    Supper = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtfourth3);


         Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
     String param1 = bundle.getString("Menuitem");

                 Toast.makeText(fourthscreen.this, param1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     if(param1.equalsIgnoreCase("BreakFast"))
     {
         Breakfast.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
     }
     else 
         if(param1.equalsIgnoreCase("Lunch"))
         {
             Lunch.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
         }
         else 
             if(param1.equalsIgnoreCase("Supper"))
             {
                 Lunch.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
             }
```

Comment: txt1.getText().toString()=BREAKFAST             txt2.getText().toString()=LUNCH

Comment: txt3.getText().toString()=SUPPER

Comment: try using  android:textStyle="bold" in xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check `String param1 = bundle.getString("Menuitem");` p**aram1** value, are you passing only "BreakFast", "Lunch" and "Supper"?

```
if(param1.equalsIgnoreCase("BreakFast"))
{
         Breakfast.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
         Lunch.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        Supper.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
else if(param1.equalsIgnoreCase("Lunch"))
{
         Lunch.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
         Breakfast.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        Supper.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
else if(param1.equalsIgnoreCase("Supper"))
{
        Supper.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        Lunch.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        Breakfast.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: is 50% work  :Lunch will not b highlight
 else if(param1.equalsIgnoreCase("Lunch"))
          {
          Breakfast.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
           Lunch.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);             
              Supper.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
          }

Comment: when i press img2 buttonToast will show "LUNCH" but lunch.txt will not b bold

Comment: i get the problem in my json file i wtite space after "LUNCH "  lunch:P)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourTextView.setTypeface(null,Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

Try default bold, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

In your xml just write the following line in TextView tag

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```